# how to deploy JAX-RS application using jersey in websphere 8.5

Tags: jersey, websphere, jax-rs, websphere-8

When I deploy my app.war in websphere 7.0. The restful web service was successful initialized.
But after I upgrade to websphere 8.5 . It failed to deploy the restful web service class.

Below is my app.war's pom.xml for jersey.

```
    <!-- restful web service -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>  

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
       <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.tag.services.testrsws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Below is the websphere error log when start the app:

> [13-3-1 13:22:44:103 CST] 000003b5 PackagesResou I   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
>     com.tag.services.testrsws
>   
> [13-3-1 13:22:44:123 CST] 000003b5 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init Uncaught.init.exception.thrown.by.servlet
>   
> [13-3-1 13:22:44:124 CST] 000003b5 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: init servlet error：{0}
>                                    javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: servlet create uncaught exception thrown by servlet
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:398)
>   
> ...
>   
> ...
>   
>  Caused by: **java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor**
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:852)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:762)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:83)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:336)

After search by google , some one says it may be webshpere server already contain the asm. So I  delete the asm.jar from my app.war WEB-INF/lib. But it still has the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except @Surge advice.
Have you try to create a shared library, and put your asm-all.jar jersery.jar into your library.And specify the shared library to your application.

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete your asm.jar from our WEB-INF/lib. On the contrary, you should instruct your websphere 8.5 to use the asm.jar in the WEB-INF/lib instead the asm.jar provided by the Websphere installation. Check out this link: [Configure Web Module Classloader](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-express-iseries&topic=trun_classload_web). You should choose **Classes loaded with local class loader first**.

**Edit based on comments:**

Looks like this is a bug in Websphere 8.5 [PM63479; 8.5: earexpander throws java.lang.incompatibleclasschangeerror](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032860). Please download PM63479 to see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: I have already  choose Classes loaded with local class loader first.But it still throw the above error.

Comment: I updated the answer. It looks like a bug and there is a patch.

Comment: I didn't update the Websphere.I have try yudong's advice. It's Ok.Thanks.